# Limit with number of integrals tending to infinity

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals

> Let $F_0(x) = \ln x$. For $n \geq 0$ and $x >0$, let $F_{n+1}(x)=\int_0^x F_n(t)dt$. Evaluate
>   $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n! F_n(1)}{\ln n}$$

Because the final intergal is from $0$ to $1$, I thought I would use the Taylor expansion of $\ln x$ for that part, but it I got stuck with a very bad summation. I also thought that maybe squeeze theorem could be used, but I am not sure how. I'm completely stuck, and out of ideas.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I leave this idea (with some details to fill):

First, by calculating some $F_n(x)$ it looks like they have the form
$$
F_n(x)=(A_n+B_n\log x)x^n.
$$
This is then verified by a direct (inductive) calculation, which also yields that the coefficients $A_n$ and $B_n$ satisfy
$$
A_0=0,\ B_0=1,\ A_n=\frac{nA_{n-1}-B_{n-1}}{n^2},\ B_n=\frac{B_{n-1}}n.
$$
First, we find that $B_n=1/n!$, and thus we have to solve
$$
A_0=0,\ A_n=\frac{nA_{n-1}-1/(n-1)!}{n^2}
$$
We are interested in the limit of $n!A_n/\ln n$. First, by the look of the recursion above, we let $C_n=n!A_n$ and find that
$$
C_0=0,\ C_n=C_{n-1}-\frac{1}{n}.
$$
We are lucky to find that
$$
C_n=-\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}.
$$
Hence,

> $$
> \lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{n!F_n(1)}{\ln n}=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\frac{-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}}{\ln n}=-1.
> $$

Here we have used the well-known result that $\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\ln n+O(1)$.